# What is it called when you say "$.something" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, I apologize if this is a vague question, but I can't seem to describe it to Google. In jQuery what is it called when something is written like this:

```
$.something({
//stuff goes here
});
```

For example in an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
//url
//type
//data
//success
});
```

I know that normal syntax is usually `$(selector).action()`, but here, there are no selectors. Is this some sort of shorthand for selecting the document?

Comment: it is called .. a FUNCTION CALL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two types of functions in jQuery: the ones defined as properties of jQuery *prototype* (also known as `$.fn`), and the ones defined on *jQuery* object - which is actually a Function - itself. `$.ajax` is example of the latter (as well as `$.post`, `$.get` etc.)

The difference is quite distinct with `map`: [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), defined [like this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L425)...

```
jQuery.extend({
  //...
  map: function( elems, callback, arg ) { ... }
}
```

... takes any collection as its param and returns an Array.

[$().map](http://api.jquery.com/map/), defined [like this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L92)...

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
   // ...
   map: function( callback ) {
     return this.pushStack( jQuery.map(this, function( elem, i ) {
       return callback.call( elem, i, elem );
     }));
   },
}
```

... is more specific, having jQuery object to map as its context, and returning a jQuery object as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info about aliases!

Answer (score 5):

That's just a loose function inside the jQuery object, usually for functions where it doesn't make sense to apply them to a DOM element.

Comment: For example: a plugin

Comment: Hm, so it's kind of like saying `ajax` is a property of `$` where `$` is defined elsewhere in jQuery's source, or essentially *is* jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `{key: value}` is the syntax for an associative array. `fn()` is the syntax for a function call.

So the pattern `$.foo({ key: value});` calls the function `$.foo`, with the map `{key: value}` as the parameter. The function `foo` just happens to be sub-classed within the jQuery namespace. In JS (and other functional languages), functions are objects, and can have parents, children, attributes, and methods, like in OO languages.

Comment: Thank you for the information about subclassing, this really helped!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation puts most of these in the [Utilities section](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/). Maybe due to this, I have seen them being referred as "the jQuery [something] utility function". We call the `$().something` **methods** of the jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks much for the link, lots of cool stuff. Also, I really appreciate the proper name for them. For the sake of future readers, I'll mark this as the correct answer. Everyone else had really useful detail though.